# Use pytest parametrize inside test

Tags: pytest, pytest-django

Let's say I have the following pytest-django tests:

```
def test_get_color_by_id(client):
    color = Color.objects.create(name="Green")
    
    response = client.get(f"/api/colors/{color.pk}/")
    assert response.status == 200
    assert response.json() == {"id": color.pk, "name": color.name}

def test_get_color_by_name(client):
    color = Color.objects.create(name="Green")
    
    response = client.get(f"/api/color_names/{color.name}/")
    assert response.status == 200
    assert response.json() == {"id": color.pk, "name": color.name}
```

There's a lot of duplication here. Would be great to use pytest's parametrize feature like below but it's not working:

```
def test_get_color(client):
    color = Color.objects.create(name="Green")
    
    with pytest.mark.parametrize("endpoint", [
        f"/api/colors/{color.pk}/",
        f"/api/color_names/{color.name}/",
    ]):

        response = client.get(f"/api/color_names/{color.name}/")
        assert response.status == 200
        assert response.json() == {"id": color.pk, "name": color.name}
```

Is this even possible or does pytest not support it?

Answer (score 0):

See [this page](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/parametrize.html) for a description of how to write parametrized tests.  The parameters are given by decorating the test function, not by entering a `with` block:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize("endpoint", [
        f"/api/colors/{color.pk}/",
        f"/api/color_names/{color.name}/",
])
def test_get_color(client, endpoint):
    color = Color.objects.create(name="Green")
    response = client.get(endpoint)

    assert response.status == 200
    assert response.json() == {"id": color.pk, "name": color.name}
```

---

Edit: I didn't read the question carefully enough, and didn't notice that the endpoint parameters were f-strings.  You can get this specific example to work by parametrizing the test function with either regular strings or lambda functions:

Regular strings:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("endpoint", [
        "/api/colors/{color.pk}/",
        "/api/color_names/{color.name}/",
])
def test_get_color(client, endpoint):
    color = Color.objects.create(name="Green")
    endpoint = endpoint.format(color=color)
    response = client.get(endpoint)

    assert response.status == 200
    assert response.json() == {"id": color.pk, "name": color.name}
```

Lambda functions:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("endpoint", [
        lambda color: f"/api/colors/{color.pk}/",
        lambda color: f"/api/color_names/{color.name}/",
])
def test_get_color(client, endpoint):
    color = Color.objects.create(name="Green")
    response = client.get(endpoint(color))

    assert response.status == 200
    assert response.json() == {"id": color.pk, "name": color.name}
```

You may also be interested in the [`pytest-subtests`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-subtests) plugin, although in my experience it's painful to use, because it causes pytest's "only rerun failed tests" options to not work like you'd expect.

Comment: This doesn't work. `color` is undefined in the `parametrize` call.